# valor de celda de una table por menu desplegable

Tags: javascript, select, html-tabla, table, celdas

Hola tengo armado una tabla con 2 listas desplegables, cuando tengo seleccionada las 2 listas quiero obtener el valor de la celda de la tabla creada, pero no logro mostrar el resultado en un label con variables, gracias

```
 <script>
 
 function datosproducto() {
    var theSelect = localidades.localidades;
        var localidadseleccionada = document.getElementById('localidadseleccionada');
        var contenidolocalidad = document.getElementById('contenidolocalidad');
        contenidolocalidad.innerHTML = ('Localidad Seleccionada: ' + theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].text);
        localidadseleccionada.innerHTML = ('Fila Seleccionada: ' + theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value);   
 
        var theSelect = producto.producto;
        var productoseleccionado = document.getElementById('productoseleccionado');
        var contenidoproducto = document.getElementById('contenidoproducto');
        contenidoproducto.innerHTML = ('Producto Seleccionado: ' + theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].text);
        productoseleccionado.innerHTML = ('Columna Seleccionada: ' + theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value);   
        
 
 var envio=document.getElementById("one").rows[1].cells[4].outerHTML;
 alert (envio);
       
    }
        </script>
```